# Shift block with position: absolute

Tags: html, css

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hptdb/)

---

This shifts the CSS-code block `.slide_panel` left by 500px.

[image: http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/h1.png]

---

I need to CSS-code shifted the unit `.slide_panel` left on the width of the `.slide_panel`

[image: http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/h2.png]

---

CSS:

```
.wrap_news{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: cyan;
    height: 500px;
}

.wrap_news .slide_panel{
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    top: 100px;
    background: red;
    padding-right: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
}

.wrap_news .slide_panel.showPanel{
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the right property to 100%, so it will be pushed just outside the left boundary:

```
right: 100%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hptdb/2/

Comment: Then you have a new problem, you no longer have the shrink-to-fit width.

Comment: What shrink-to-fit? I don't see it in the original fiddle, you mean that it's not centered?

Answer (score 0):

you can make

```
right: 100%;
```

and you can use table if you new in css

```
<table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="50%" align="right">left</td>
<td valign="top" width="50%">right</td>
</tr>
</table>
```